# jquery.post not passing data to php file

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am having trouble getting the jquery.post method to pass a variable to a php file. 
I can print the variable to a div using javascript okay but when I pass it to the php file it will only return the fallback value I have put in.
Can you suggest why it might not be working?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function vwidth(){
    var vwWidth = window.innerWidth;
    document.getElementById('printVar').innerHTML = vwWidth; //test js variable - ok
    $.post( "listGen.php", {vwWid: vwWidth});
}
</script>

<body onLoad="vwidth()" onResize="vwidth()">
<div id="printVar">
</div>
<div>
<?php 
    include 'listGen.php';
    echo $viewwidth; 
?>
</div>
```

listGen.php -

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['vwWid'])){
        $viewwidth = $_POST['vwWid'];
        }
        else {
        $viewwidth = 1200;
        }
?>
```

Comment: your PHP doesn't have return any response, just echo the number, after that handle the response in the `$.post` success block

Comment: I don't really need any return response, I want to use the variable in the php file, but it doesn't seem to be getting through

Comment: if thats the case, that should work just fine, just make sure the php is in the correct path, the easiest way to debug if works is to actually echo `$_POST['vwWid']` in the PHP side, and then check you network tab using your browser, if its there echoed, it means the server side received it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated***

Your JS Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function vwidth(){
    var vwWidth = window.innerWidth;
    document.getElementById('printVar').innerHTML = vwWidth; //test js variable - ok
    $.ajax({

      url: 'listGen.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {vwWid: vwWidth},
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
       $("#myDiv").text(data);
     }

   });

}
</script>

<body onLoad="vwidth()" onResize="vwidth()">
<div id="printVar">
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Your PHP page:

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['vwWid'])){

 response =  $_POST['vwWid'];

 }else {

   response = 'You did not get vwWid in your post request.';

  }

echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: I can get the variable to display in a div okay. I don't really want the
1200 value, it is only a fallback. But this is all that is being echo'd.
The problem is with the $.post not getting through to the php file...

Comment: That is because you are including the page in your code.  Ajax works by making a request to a php page server side, the server then sends the response back to the requesting page and displays the results.

Comment: This works and I am now using this (albeit, the condensed $.post version). Probably a better way of doing it anyway.